# Why does Streamlit not find my python file?

Tags: python, macos, streamlit

I have Streamlit working in terminal i.e. the following runs in terminal:

```
$ streamlit hello
```

I am trying to create an app with the online tutorial but encounter an error - see below

`https://docs.streamlit.io/en/latest/tutorial/create_a_data_explorer_app.html#let-s-put-it-all-together`

I have saved the following in as uber_pickups.py

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

st.title('Uber pickups in NYC')

(base) lf-mac-0250:~ alastairhayes$ streamlit hello

  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Local URL: http://localhost:8501
  Network URL: http://172.20.10.2:8501
```

`^C`  Stopping...

```
(base) lf-mac-0250:~ alastairhayes$ streamlit run uber_pickups.py
Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...

Error: Invalid value: File does not exist: uber_pickups.py
```

Where am I going wrong? 
I have python 3.7.6
Many thanks!

Comment: You say you "have saved the following as uber_pickups.py" - but saved it *where*, exactly?  Evidently you didn't save it in the same directory that you're running the terminal command from.  Either give a full pathname to where the file is actually located, or give a `cd` command to move to the containing directory before giving the command.

Comment: Thanks Jason! Winner. I just did Streamlit run /Users/alastairhayes/Desktop etc etc and it worked as you suggested. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the file does not exist, which suggests that either the file is not saved in the correct location or the file name is misspelled.

A few things you can try to resolve the issue:

- Make sure that the `uber_pickups.py` file is saved in the same directory where you are running the streamlit run command as someone already mentioned above. You can use the `cd` command to navigate to the correct directory before running the `streamlit run uber_pickups.py` command.
- Double-check the spelling of the file name to make sure it matches exactly, including capitalization.
- Try specifying the full path to the `uber_pickups.py` file in the streamlit run command. For example, if the file is saved in the `/Users/alastairhayes/Documents/Streamlit` directory, you can run the command as follows:

  `streamlit run /Users/alastairhayes/Documents/Streamlit/uber_pickups.py`

I hope one of these solutions helps.

Comment: This is the only correct solution imho.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows OS, you may try the steps below:

1. First, you need to download Anaconda:
   https://www.anaconda.com/
2. Open the Anaconda PowerShell Prompt and type the following:

   `conda list`

   `pip uninstall streamlit`
3. Then, create a new environment, and test out the following:

   `pip install streamlit`

   `streamlit hello`
4. Finally, you can test out streamlit on your code, replace your_app with the actual name of your file. Make sure you are in the same directory as your source code file.

   `streamlit run your_app.py`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.   First, we have to run the program. It then displays

```
Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
command:
```

Copy and paste the command and run it. This worked for me in vs code

Answer (score 0):

I had an error, like yours. And for me it was simple:

You don't need to install Anaconda. But with its direct execution in the python program, it is necessary to declare `python -m` before `streamlit run`. Like: `python -m streamlit run`

When Anaconda installed, you will need open the Anaconda prompt and just enter the command `streamlit run`.

But you must ensure that streamlit is installed inside Anaconda.

For that, you must use the command `pip install streamlit` also in the Anaconda prompt.

If you installed python, used the `pip install streamlit` command in the cdm and only afterwards, installed Anaconda... it will continue to give an error, because you have two development environments isolated from each other.